# How to animate camera to polyline (Google maps)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have polyline string like "s_~fGwyptMSkFnBK".

(swift 4)

```
let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: GMSPath(fromEncodedPath:polylineString))
polyline.map = self.mapView
```

How to animate camera to this polyline?

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the first and last coordinates of the polyline and animate the camera movement in this way.

```
let vancouver = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 49.26, longitude: -123.11)
let calgary = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.05,longitude: -114.05)
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: vancouver, coordinate: calgary)
let camera = mapView.camera(for: bounds, insets: UIEdgeInsets())!
mapView.camera = camera
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/views